# UITableView do not respond some touches while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

When `tableView` is scrolling with high speed, and user tries to stop it by touch, `tableView` keeps scrolling. And user can stop scrolling `tableView` only after two or three touches. If speed of `tableView` scrolling is low, `tableView` respond touches well.

The tableView displays cells with a lot of subviews, and I localized problem on one view.
If I set `problemView.userInteractionEnabled = NO`, scrolling works well. To set `userInteractionEnabled = NO` for all subviews of `problemView` but not for `problemView`, do not help.

Here image of diplaying cell, the `problemView` is view with red frame.

[image: Displaying cell]

Could somebody to give an advice, how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities:

Your custom view, or one of its superviews, has userInteractionEnabled set to NO.

There is another view on top of your custom view, or on top of the table view within the custom view.

The custom view that the table view is inside is smaller than the table view (with clipsToBounds=NO, a subview that extends beyond the bounds of its parent can be seen but not normally interacted with). Or the same for another view in the stack.

The custom view (or one of its superviews) overrides pointInside:withEvent: or hitTest:withEvent: incorrectly.

Comment: To set `problemView.userInteractionEnabled = NO` solves problem.
For all subviews `clipsToBounds = YES`
And there are no custom views with overrided methods `pointInside:withEvent:` or `hitTest:withEvent:`

Answer (score 0):

It might be that it thinks you are editing it in some way. Try `allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES`. [Here is more information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsSelection) with using the UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NSTimer inside the UITableViewCell then I have experienced anomalous actions as you have discussed.  In such case you need to replace implicitly scheduled timer with explicitly scheduled timer.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that having `userInteractionEnabled = true` with a click handler on subviews in the cell broke the scrolling. Not sure *why* this is the case though. I solved this in my case by using `didSelectRowAt` on the tableview instead of having custom click handlers on the subviews. Then both the scrolling and the click handling worked as I wanted to.